# Value in .h file not defined in .rc file

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, conditional-compilation, rc

I'm working on creating build configurations based on a previous question of mine.  I've got the Build Configurations created, and I have conditional declarations for the different builds in a file called `custom.h`.  It currently looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#if defined(ELITE_BUILD)
    #define BUILD 3 // 1: personal, 2: select, 3: elite
#elif defined(SELECT_BUILD)
    #define BUILD 2
#elif defined(PERSONAL_BUILD)
    #define BUILD 1
#endif
```

In one of my .rc files there is an include for `versionconfig.h` that looks like this (somewhat redacted):

```
#if BUILD == 1
#define STRDESCRIPTION  "Personal Edition"
#elif BUILD == 2
#define STRDESCRIPTION  "Select Edition"
#elif BUILD == 3
#define STRDESCRIPTION  "Elite Edition"
#pragma message(STRDESCRIPTION)
#endif
```

I added the `#pragma` command as a logging effort.  After that include, the relevant parts of the .rc file looks like this (again, a bit redacted for brevity):

```
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "FileDescription", STRDESCRIPTION
        END
    END
END
```

When I attempt to compile this project I get the error `error RC2104 : undefined keyword or key name: STRDESCRIPTION`.  I'm at a bit of a loss.  The value exists, I can log it immediately after setting it, and there is no `#undef` command for it.

-- EDITED --

If I add placeholder defines outside of the if block the project will compile, but the values aren't showing up, so my problem appears to be related to conditional definitions.  What's confusing me most at this point is that I can put a `#pragma message` command inside the conditional block and it's executed properly, but the values defined there are non-existent.  Hoping someone can shed some light on this for me.

Comment: If I'd recently generated the files that might be possible.  However, the relevant parts of the files haven't changed in quite some time.  The only files that changed were `custom.h` and that was to have check for Variables defined in the Preprocessor section of the Build Configurations.  `versionconfig.h` and the `.rc` file haven't been modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it.  In Visual Studio you have to set pre-processor definitions for the Resource Files separately from the Project.  As soon as I added `ELITE_BUILD` to the pre-processor section for the resource everything worked as expected.